# What am i doing wrong with random?

Tags: xna, c#, random

I have some code that uses a random number to determine whether an object is special or not. I use this code on each of 4 objects that are reset every so often.

```
Random rand = new Random();

int i = rand.Next(1, 25);

if (i == 1)
{
    thiss.typer = "boulder";
    thiss.texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("rock");
}
else if (i == 2)
{
    thiss.typer = "ice";
    thiss.texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ice");
}
else if (i == 3)
{
    thiss.typer = "bomb";
    thiss.texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("bomb");
}
else
    thiss.typer = "normal";
```

But every time I execute this code, when it creates the 4 objects, when it makes one of them special, it makes all of them special for some reason. Is there something wrong with this code, or will i have to show more of my code to shed some light on it?

Answer (score 14):

I can think of two reasons why this could happen.

Firstly, maybe you accidentally share a reference between your objects, so that `thiss.typer` refers to the same object in all 4 cases.

Secondly, and more likely, the Random-objects you create share the same seed, so that rand.Next returns the same number in all 4 instances. 
When you do `new Random()` without an argument, the seed is based on the current system time. If you do it multiple times in quick succession, the seeds might be the same.

You could try using the same Random object, instead of creating a new one each time it is used. This way you also avoid creating lots of objects unneccessarily.

Comment: +1 I've had issues like this in the past due to using different random objects in quick succession. I get around it by having one static `Random` object somewhere in my code that any class can access.

Comment: If you have a static `Random` object keep in mind that random isn't thread safe: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b3ta19y.aspx

Comment: *The default seed value is derived from the system clock and has finite resolution. As a result, different Random objects that are created in close succession by a call to the default constructor will have identical default seed values and, therefore, will produce identical sets of random numbers. This problem can be avoided by using a single Random object to generate all random numbers.* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9.aspx

Comment: +1 Don't create a new random every time you need to use it. Use the same one regularly. This is what they were made for.

Comment: @tobsen yes it's not thread safe - I have disassembled the code I don't see any loops in InternalSample(). This means that, yes, internal state could get corrupted, but who cares? The worst that can happen is we get random non-deterministic results, *that's what we are looking for* :). If you are really worried you can use thread dataslots to have a `Random` object per thread. https://gist.github.com/2782210

Comment: @JonathanDickinson according to the comments in the msdn article I linked to, the worst that can happen is that Random will return 0 for all subsequent calls when used from different threads! I don't think that this is what users are expecting. See also the comments here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx . Nice workaround for the ThreadStatic attribute though ;)

Comment: @tobsen oh that is bad. Getting streams of 0 is still statistically random but not likely the type of random you are looking for ;).

Comment: @Richard: In response to tobsen's comment, just make sure you mark the `Random` object with the [`[ThreadStatic]` annotation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx).